# Issues installing OpenCV with Python 3 on macOS High Sierra

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, opencv, homebrew

I have tried to install opencv3 with homebrew on my mac. I have run:

```
$ brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --with-python3 --HEAD
```

When I enter this command, opencv is installed but it says:

```
Warning: opencv: this formula has no --with-contrib option so it will be ignored!
Warning: opencv: this formula has no --with-python3 option so it will be ignored!
Warning: opencv: this formula has no --HEAD option so it will be ignored!
```

I have noticed that opencv will work within python 2 but I would like it to work in python 3 as well.

I am using python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it using conda-forge https://github.com/conda-forge/opencv-feedstock

conda config --add channels conda-forge

conda install opencv